# Cannot start the "Strangers & Freaks" mission, game soft-locks right afterward

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Basically having played a lot of GTA V, now I'm going back to redo missions and mess about.

I thought I'd try 'hunting' with Trevor, and when I try the strangers & freaks mission retry the Xbox 360 informs me that it needs to make a 'restore point' and is this ok? I click yes, the message repeats until I click 'no' and then it reverts to the character, immobile; unable to move, act or even be hit (it was fun listening to a biker near the bar insulting him for about 10 mins...)

I also have a similar problem where the game works just fine until I try to access the stock market with any character, after which almost all functionality is lost; and the game becomes 'drive around and shoot things.'

If I did not have such a profound love of this; it's cultural references, it's humor, and all of its other elements, it probably wouldn't bug me this much; but I do and would really like to not have these problems without having to begin again from the very start...

Comment: Hi User!  In the case of the stock market, is it that the game still works but all objectives disappear? (or did you mean that you can't continue since those two options basicly softlock the game?)

Comment: Hi! Great (wow)  yes... to basically... both.

If I bring up the stock market it kind of ½  crashes;   the ability to trade disappears, and once out of the screen- no ability to make phone calls, booty calls etc etc   and I think no ability to swap character either.

The 'softlock' [? what a cool phrase]  happens when I go back to retry 'hunting' w Trevor & it speaks of the need to make a restore point first, & just loops until you press the red button & then he stands there, like a statue.

Occasionally in a delivery mission, if you enter a rival pickup he'll sit there, or leave running

Comment: I hope to see some kind of answer then! A softlock is a condition where the game still responds (ie, can walk or can open the start menu) but the actual game (like controlling your character while interacting with objects) is unavailable. - I wonder if the issue here might be the something like a smudge/scrach on the disc?

Comment: I bl***y hope not! The place I bought the original disk from, already replaced it with another when I had *facepalm* moment lifting the unit up while everything was being accessed..... drew a scary looking circle all the way around the centre of my original play disk.

However I've been using a different disk; have backed up the saves onto an ext drive in case I need to reinstall them [it cd be an hdd problem as well, right?]...but if the saves were corrupted when the original disk was scratched, I'm doomed I suppose.

This softcrash wd b the reduced functionality. The freezing=diffr

Comment: Going to sleep shortly. The odd italics in prev post were unintentional.

Comment: @user168757 is the game save you are trying to play 100%?  I'm reading that this is a possible problem, and some players have reverted back to a save where the game is not 100% complete and they can replay the missions.  I've also read that playing the game offline (disabling the internet on the console) has been effective for some also.